# Vb.net run apication server-side?

Tags: html, windows, vb.net, server, tcp

I want to build a website which uses HTML buttons that use the POST method to trigger a vb.net function on the "server" host PC via the TCP... In fact this is how I build applications on our local network. I was thinking this could be handy if it were also applied to a website on the WWW.

My vb.net applications typically receive an input from the html POST method, use that input to calculate or retrieve data and generate a new html page for the users viewing (typically displaying the requested data in some form or other)

I had built a simple website on a synology NAS before which will not run any vb.net applications because its not windows based.

What I was looking at was a HP Proliant Microserver that has windows server running on it.

I've never done this before but was intrested to know if this concept of posting html text to trigger server-side running vb.net applications would work on a windows server or is there far more involved?

Comment: Okay I currently have a bunch of vb.net applications that listen on a tcp connection for HTML POST methods example of such a post is REQUESTlengthsWOOD this is intercepted by the vb.net program and broken down and recognizes the request is for avaulable wood lengths. It then responds to the client with redirection to an automatically generated HTML page on the server wich in this example shows wood beam lengths currently available . I already use this method successfully in a subnetwork but wanted to try my luck ussing a website onntge actually internet.

Comment: Its more of a hobby than anything else so I'm not particularly put off by that blocking issue yet... thanks for your answer 